# When I make a transaction, how is it broadcasted to other clients?

Tags: transactions

It's a really nooby question, and with no doubt asked before, but if someone could tell me

a)how are other clients found

b)how is the information send to them

(please explain in a simple way, because I haven't messed with the bitcoin protocol itself)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. They're found using a gossip protocol.
2. Transactions are sent using this structure: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions

Comment: While these links probably answer the question, would you please put some more explanation here?

Comment: Other clients are not found using DHT. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/how-do-bitcoin-clients-find-each-other

Comment: sorry guys. answered this way back before even doing proper research on it :( - can't delete because it's accepted so I tried adding some more info.