# Who is a first miner that receive a transaction from end-user?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

This is a First Question. 
As you already know, the blockchain like Bitcoin, Ethereum is a software program based on peer to peer network system. so I am wondering that who is a first miner that receive a transaction from end-user that create a transaction such as bitcoin-core program.

This is a Second Question. 
I know that SPV node are End-users that use wallet program such as Bitcoin-core.
End-user is a just SPV node that can't verify some transactions and provide information to full-node to quickly find transaction.

1. Does End-user has full-node list to provide hint of transaction information ?
2. If answer of above question is yes, how they know full-node? where is source of full-node list?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I have a hard time following your question. How is this related to Ethereum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> who is a first miner that receive a transaction

Each full-node ends up sharing information with a small number of other active full-nodes. I believe there is a node discovery process primed by an initial list hardcoded into the node software. The nodes thus form a dynamic self-organising network with multiple hops between distantly connected nodes. Which miner first receives a transaction therefore depends somewhat on where the transaction originated. It is effectively somewhat random, or at least undirected.

> SPV node are End-users that use wallet program such as Bitcoin-core

I believe Bitcoin core is a full-node not SPV. Electrum is an example of an SPV node.

> Does End-user has full-node list

No

Note that an SPV node is a lightweight node which does not have a copy of the full Blockchain, a journal (list) of all transactions. SPV nodes effectively  ask other nodes they know about to verify transactions for them.

Bitcoin nodes do not need a list of all other nodes, only of a few nodes nearby (in a topological sense).

See [How do Bitcoin clients find each other?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3536)

> how SPV node can provide transaction information to full-node without full-node list

By telling an interesting fact to three friends who each talk to three of their friends who all talk to three of their friends  (and so on), you can start a rumour that spreads across a school, across a city or to millions of people across the planet.

Comment: Hello :) 
In your last comment, you commented "no" so, how SPV node can provide transaction information to full-node without full-node list?

Comment: @Hyunsoo: Answer updated

Comment: Good example, but SPV node does not know the information about any full-node according to your comment. so how can SPV node talk with full-node initially?

Comment: @Hyunsoo: I wrote above *"there is a node discovery process primed by an initial list hardcoded into the node software"* -- that's a simplification but there are DNS names and hardcoded lists for some initial full-node contacts from which the SPV client can eventually find a useful set of full-nodes to talk to. You can (and probably should) use the [Ask Question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at top right for follow-up questions ("peer discovery") that are more than just seeking clarification. Better to have many separate questions than one enormous list of questions.