# Do I need a full node to perform OP_RETURN transactions?

Tags: op-return, full-node

I want to build a services that allows people to perform OP_RETURN for proof of existence. Do I need to run a full node to do this (then e.g. using the OP_RETURN PHP scripts from https://github.com/coinspark/php-OP_RETURN)? I have found no API that allows to do this.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run a full node in order to submit a transaction, regardless of which OP codes that transaction contains.  Any node that can submit transactions to the Bitcoin network will do.

What you should look for instead, is a library in your chosen language that allows you to construct [transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) manually, rather than using templates for typical payment transactions.  Once you have a transaction constructed, you can broadcast it to the network via whichever type of node you feel like.

Comment: thanks! So is there a predefined list of bootstrap IP addresses or do I have  to define a node to connect to?

Comment: @Chris, this may help:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/what-is-a-dns-seed-node-vs-a-seed-node  Also, you may want to run a full node anyways, if you are trying to start a service on top of Bitcoin.  It's best to rely on your own node of the network, rather than someone else's.