# How to setup seed node?

Tags: altcoin-development, cryptonote

I have compiled and build my own coin using cryptonote fork.
After that i have printed genesis block.
Then I pasted this genesis block hash and rebuild the binaries.
But, my question is:-

What to do next?

I have all this on my local pc.

How to start seed node?

I have purchased digitalocean VPS.

What files do i need to transfer to VPS.and what commands do i need to run on vps.

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

I have been in the same boat since last 2 weeks. Made a BTC clone out of a very old source code found online.

I have been a bit successful as well.

**All the below assumes that you are running Ubuntu.**

After compiling I was able to run it using the ./xyzcoind

I did find out that you would need at least two nodes to test. I read this somewhere and also validated this. Can not start mining till there are two servers talking to each other.

I have done this by setting up two small servers on Azure. One connects to the other.

./xyzcoind -connect=a.b.c.d

To test if it is running well or not you may goto .xyzcoin in your home folder and check debug.log

To set up the dns seed node, the parameter can be directly specified in chainparam.cpp if you are using bitcoin source in line that reads as "

> vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("someaddress.com or IP addy",
>   "someaddress.com"));

And then you need to add all the seed node IP address to the A records where ever you have your domain name from. You might need to do it on your own if you have a privater server or can use cpanel depending on the scenario at your end. I did it via cpanel as I have domains hosted with siteground.

some more details on below link

> [What is a DNS seed node vs a Seed Node?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/what-is-a-dns-seed-node-vs-a-seed-node)

Comment: What command did you use to build your binaries, was it make -j. Am having problem building the binaries so that I can have a value to put in the GENESIS_COINBASE_TX_HEX="". Am using ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

i ran some instance of node on various server and noted the ip of them

1)change file

> net.cpp

```
static const char *strMainNetDNSSeed[][2] = { 

{"aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa","aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa"}, {"bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb","bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb"}, {"ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc","ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc"},

};
```

Now convert you ip to hex and add on line no 1240(search on basis of function name and not by line number):

```
unsigned int pnSeed[] =
{   
0xa5esadf3d, 0xa5ssddf, 0xa5sd1s3, 0x68ec1asc,
}
```

Thats all, now when ever you run ./altcoin -daemon it will directly connect with any running node among mentioned above