# DNS seeds and security

Tags: bitcoin-core, dns

In the case of website like bitcoin.org some people noticed suspicious things on website and reported. Later Andrew Chow did some analysis and it seems DNS records were changed for the domain: https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/Bitcoin.org/issues/3743#issuecomment-926189200

How would users know if one of the domains used by [DNS seeds](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/17410/) in Bitcoin Core will be hacked and resolve to malicious nodes? What will be the impact of this until owner of domain knows about it if lasts for few hours?

Comment: This would mostly* impact fresh nodes, because the DNS is only used when the node doesn't already have its own list (`peers.dat`). A node checks 3 seeds at a time, so it would require coordination. For new nodes it takes a few hours just to sync the blockchain.


* = some recent versions of Bitcoin Core would needlessly check the seeds