# What's the relationship between Bittorrent and Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, decentralization, source-code

I know both implementations make use of decentralization, but is Bitcoin using any technology that was developed by Bittorrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is much overlap, beyond the conceptual "making connections between nodes over the internet" part.

There are also hash functions in both, and probably a few more very basic constructions.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which both protocols use is peer discovery and bootstrapping.

Bitcoin full node implementation used by most nodes (Bitcoin Core) used IRC channels to get IP addresses of nodes earlier. It uses [DNS seeds](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/17410/) right now and BitTorrent uses DHT nodes.

There is not much difference in the concept.

Comment: That's not completely correct, the BitTorrent DHT still has seed nodes same as everything else. You can't bootstrap peer discovery in a network with absolutely no knowledge of its participants.

Comment: Not sure which part of the answer is not correct. And I don't think I mentioned anywhere that you can bootstrap peer discovery with no knowledge of its participants.

Comment: I assume what @Claris means is: the DHT isn't a seeding mechanism. You still need seed nodes to get connected to the DHT.

Comment: That’s right, there’s no real difference in the concept.