# How are mined blocks broadcasted in a distributed environment?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, block, protocol

I understand that after the golden nonce is found by the miner he broadcasts the block and the other miners verify it. But I don't understand how they broadcast it because bitcoin is completely distributed with no servers to store the ip to distribute it to. How does a new miner know whom to distribute it to?

Any help is really appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miners operate nodes (as do many non-miners). These nodes make connections to each other. When a node receives a block or transaction from another node, it will check the block or transaction and then send it to the other nodes it is connected to. In this way, a block or transaction reaches every node in the network.

The miners do not connect to some central server or service in order to broadcast blocks to the network. They simply send the blocks to the nodes that they are connected to and the blocks are then relayed to all nodes.

As for how a node figures out who to connect to, please see this question: [How does the bitcoin client make the initial connection to the bitcoin network?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/how-does-the-bitcoin-client-make-the-initial-connection-to-the-bitcoin-network)

Comment: Actually, many miners do connect to a number of central servers or services to help get their blocks distributed as widely and quickly as possible. Punch "bitcoin relay network" into your favorite search engine and you'll find a number of them. These are not necessary, as simple node relaying is sufficient. But the faster you relay, the more likely you are to get your mining reward. So there has been lots of optimization efforts.